# Perl defining undefined keys

Tags: perl, hash, key, undefined, autovivification

The following code prints `Key defined 3`.
Why is Perl defining the key `ABC` ? I was expecting all the three checks to be false.What am I doing incorrectly ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my %Hash;

if(defined $Hash{'ABC'})
{
    printf("Key defined 1\n");
}

if(defined $Hash{'ABC'}{'Status'})
{
    printf("Key defined 2\n");
}

if(defined $Hash{'ABC'})
{
    printf("Key defined 3\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `$Hash{'ABC'}{'Status'}` autovivifies the ABC key (see [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification)):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %Hash;

if(defined $Hash{'ABC'})
{
    printf("Key defined 1\n");
}
print Dumper(\%Hash);

if(defined $Hash{'ABC'}{'Status'})
{
    printf("Key defined 2\n");
}
print Dumper(\%Hash);

if(defined $Hash{'ABC'})
{
    printf("Key defined 3\n");
}
print Dumper(\%Hash);

__END__

$VAR1 = {};
$VAR1 = {
          'ABC' => {}
        };
Key defined 3
$VAR1 = {
          'ABC' => {}
        };
```

See also [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDiver) and the [`autovivification` pragma](http://p3rl.org/autovivification), which prevent autovivification.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Hash{'ABC'}{'Status'}
```

is short for

```
$Hash{'ABC'}->{'Status'}
```

What you have there is a dereference. When a variable being dereferenced is undefined, autovivification kicks in to create the appropriate type of variable. This makes the above equivalent to

```
( $Hash{'ABC'} //= {} )->{'Status'}
```

You can avoid autovivification by avoiding dereferencing something undefined

```
if ($Hash{'ABC'} && defined $Hash{'ABC'}{'Status'})
```

Or you can use `no autovivification;`

```
no autovivification;
if (defined $Hash{'ABC'}{'Status'})
```